# Why some attributes can't search in storefront?

Tags: magento2, product, attributes, search, indexing

I have two custom attributes, all with these options:

[image: attr1]

[image: scope]

Products are imported programatically by cron, set in website and have these attributes. 
When I search one attribute I see results but by the second I receive these notice:

> Your search returned no results.

Website is in production, I refreshed the cache and reindex indexers... 
Can you help me to solve these issue? The two attributes should be searchable in storefront but one isn't.

Attribute thant isn't searchable only have numbers, but is stored in text and i save it in cron in a string.

**EDIT**
I see that attribute value what can search is visible in backend in all stores but other attribute value only is visible in one store, how can  put value visibility in all stores?

Comment: Is these attributes assigned to attribute set?

Comment: Yes @RanjitShinde I see these attributes in frontend but I can't search it